# Devise Resetting Password Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

When I click the "Send me reset password instructions" link for Devise, I get;

```
ArgumentError in Devise/passwords#create

Extracted source (around line #5):

2:   
3: Someone has requested a link to change your password, and you can do this through the link below.
4:  
5: <%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @resource.reset_password_token) %>  
6:  
7: If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.
8: Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.
```

Anybody know why I'm getting this error? I haven't changed anything in this file.

Comment: Which version are you using and have you upgraded recently? Presumably it was ok before?

Comment: I haven't tested it before and I don't know what version I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this file is a template for email that would be send to user. You should check mailer setup...

Comment: config/environments/development.rb 
    app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb

Comment: I don't have devise/mailer.rb in my mailers

Comment: This part of **devise** is about restoring password. What about other parts, do they works? Signup? Login?

Comment: Well, just installed new void rails application with devise from scratch. Everything works for me. Don't know how to help though.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
resources :passwords
```

in your routes.rb

Also you need to setup a mailer

```
# Setup for production - deliveries, no errors raised
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.yourmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :domain => ENV['SMTP_USER'],
  :user_name => ENV['SMTP_USER'],
  :password => ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'],
}
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't change anything.

Comment: Where do I setup the mailer?

Comment: I don't think you should add a passwords resource into the routes file at all.